# Retry only when 5xx error is encountered Spring boot WebClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webclient

I have followed few suggestions around to make a retry attempt only when I get 5xx error and straight away throw exception otherwise. But the code example I got doesn't seems to be working. It's not retrying for any of the exceptions (be it 4xx or 5xx).

Here is my code

```
public Mono<String> call(String input) {

    log.info("Sending echo call for: {}", input);

    return webClient.get()
            .uri(format("/echo/%s", input))
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).acceptCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError,
                    response -> Mono.error(new ServiceException("Server error", response.rawStatusCode())))
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .timeout(ofMillis(60_000L))
            .retryWhen(
                    backoff(3L, ofSeconds(4L))
                            .jitter(0d)
                            .filter(ServiceException.class::isInstance)
                            .doAfterRetry(retrySignal -> log.info("Retry call: " + retrySignal))
                            .onRetryExhaustedThrow((retryBackoffSpec, retrySignal) -> retrySignal.failure())
            )
            .doOnError(throwable -> log.error("Call failure: {}", throwable.getMessage()))
            .doOnSuccess(response -> log.info("Success: {}", response));
}
```

Anyone can help me figure out what's wrong with the code or can suggest an alternative approach. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, it should work.

```java
   
final WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().build();
final Mono<String> body = webClient
                .get()
                .uri("URL")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .retryWhen(Retry
                        .backoff(3, Duration.ofSeconds(2))
                        .filter(this::is5xxServerError)
                );
        System.out.println(body.block());


private boolean is5xxServerError(Throwable throwable) {
        return throwable instanceof WebClientResponseException &&
                ((WebClientResponseException) throwable).getStatusCode().is5xxServerError();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have already tried that and this doesn't work when I get the 500. I get the 'WebClientRequestException' instead of the 'WebClientResponseException', hence it doesn't retry because it returns false.

Comment: Ok, did you try by replacing WebClientResponseException with WebClientRequestException in above code?

Comment: Yes, Unfortunately WebClientRequestException doesn't have any method or way to get the status code.

Comment: If you know that code is giving WebClientRequestException and you want to retry then you can write logic like this.                                                        
                                                 .retryWhen(Retry
      .backoff(3, Duration.ofSeconds(2))
      .filter(throwable -> throwable instanceof WebClientRequestException)
    );